# Is it possible to add a T-SQL function/query to an adapter whos table is build in the datasetdesigner

Tags: vb.net, t-sql, visual-studio-2013

I want to add a T-SQL query to an existing Datatable Adapter from the datasetdesigner.xsd .
Is this possible in the designer?
If not, can I use an existing adapter from the designer when I hardcode my query?

Cheers steven

@Tim I did that already. I right clicked and added a sql query : here is the query

```
Declare @start integer
declare @currentkey varchar(20)
set @rowcount = (select MAX(ID) from Z_SKM)
set @start =1


while @start <= @rowcount
begin

set @currentkey= (select branche_firma_key from z_skm where Id = @start )

if(@currentkey = Null OR @currentkey ='')
begin

end
else
begin
UPDATE [sysdba].[Z_SKM]
set Branche_firma_val = (select Text from ZDEFPROPERTY
                        join ZSYSPROPERTY
                        on ZDEFPROPERTY.ZDEFPROPERTYID=ZSYSPROPERTY.ZDEFPROPERTYID
                        where @currentkey= ZSYSPROPERTY.SYSPROPERTYID and valuetype    ='branch' and text not like '% EH' and text not like '% GH' and text not like '% alt' )

 WHERE ID = @start



end
 set @start = @start + 1
end
```

It works in the mssql - servermanager but IT doesnt work in visual studio by rightclicking adapter, add query and insert it..
Is there another syntax to use?
Or do I need to hardcode it?

Cheers steven

Comment: You just have to right-click on the table-adapter in the designer and click "add query". http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kda44dwy.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I made the function work by saving it as procedure in the sql server. After that I was able to call the procedure in the Visual studio dataset designer by rightclik on the adapter and click "add query" -> "saved procedure"